# XCode shows errors that doesn't exists

Tags: ios, xcode

My XCode sometimes shows errors that doesn't real exist, because it compiles and runs the project. 
These errors are often "Use of undeclared identify 'MyClass'", but the .h files was imported by the pch file and not directly in the .m file.

Sometimes this errors goes away simply closing XCode and reopening the project, or cleaning DeriverData folder, but sometimes these doesn't disappear.

Someone have a permanent solution?

Comment: which version you are using???xcode

Comment: the last, 8.3.2